# BSD sockets on port number range

Tags: sockets, bsd

I am using UDP BSD sockets in C, and I need a way to receive all packets sent to my IP on a range of different port numbers. My current code can detect packets only on one port that I specify. Is this possible to do, or should I look for another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your current code such as what?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Depending on your environment you might use raw sockets or you might firewall rules to redirect traffic destined for many ports to a single port (i.e. iptables redirect, pf divert etc) and thus get the traffic no matter what original port it was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start a listener for each port number you want to listen to

Comment: i didnt mention in my original post that iam using udp not tcp would that make a difference?

Comment: @blinded_ravager I doubt it, udp as well as tcp needs to listen to a specific port